# create ruby object if all attributes are defined

Tags: ruby

I have a hash that is defining some variables as such:

```
        event_details = {
            :title => title(event),
            :desc => desc(event),
            :url => url(event),
            :datetime => datetime(event),
            :address => address,
            :lat => coords["lat"],
            :lng => coords["lng"]
        }
```

and I want to create an "event" object

```
event = Event.new(event_details)
```

Now I only want to create the object `event` if and only if all the attributes are defined and not nil, for example, the lat and lng variables are sometimes nil, and I do not want to create that event object.

I was thinking about having a rescue clause in my event class, but I am not sure how I only create the instance of event, and validate the presence of each attribute. any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How about `event = Event.new(event_details) unless event_details.values.any(&:nil?)
`?

Comment: + 1 @CarySwoveland pretty much what I was going to write. :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland - `Event.new({})` would pass, even though no attribute has been set.

Comment: Ah, yes, @BroiSatse, I missed the "are defined". Thanks. I adjusted and posted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
keys = [:title, :desc, :url, :datetime, :address, :lat, :lng]

event = Event.new(event_details) unless
        (keys-event_details.keys].any? || event_details.values.any?(&:nil?)
```

or

```
if (keys-event_details.keys].any? || event_details.values.any?(&:nil?)
  <..action..>
else
  event = Event.new(event_details)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
class Event
  attr_accessor :title, :desc

  RequiredKeys = [:title, :desc]

  def initialize(hash = {})
    missing_keys = RequiredKeys - hash.keys
    raise "Required keys missing:  #{missing_keys.join(', ')}" unless missing_keys.empty?
    hash.each do |key, value|
      public_send("#{key}=", value);
    end
  end
end
```